# componentWillReceiveProps not called after redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I'm building a react native app and using redux to handle the state. I am running into a situation where one of my containers is not updating immediately when the redux state is changed.

Container:

```
...
class ContainerClass extends Component<Props, State> {
    ...
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Object) {
        console.log('WILL RECEIVE PROPS:', nextProps);
    }
    ...
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return <SubComponent data={data} />
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.data
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContainerClass);
```

Reducer:

```
...
export default function reducer(state = initalState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case getType(actions.actionOne):
            console.log('SETTING THE STATE');
            return { ...state, data: action.payload };
        ...
    ...
...
```

In a different random component, I am dispatching a call with the actionOne action, which I confirm prints out the relevant console.log. However, the console.log in the componentWillReceiveProps in the container is not printed.

The component that dispatches the call is a modal that has appeared over the Container, and closes automatically after the call is dispatched and the state is updated. What is weird is that although the Container isn't updated immediately, if I navigate to a different page and then back to the Container page, the state is in fact updated.

EDIT: Initial state is:

```
const initialState: Store = {
    data: []
}
```

And the way I dispatch is in a different component which gets called as a new modal (using react-native-navigation) from Container:

```
fnc() {
    ...
    setData(data.concat(newDatum));
    ...
}
```

Where `setData` and `data` are the redux dispatch action and the part of the store respectively that is passed in on props from the Container (which has `setData` and `data` through mapStateToProps shown above and a mapDispatchToProps which I didn't show).

Comment: Maybe your actual code is different, but you have an unclosed paren in mapStateToProps

Comment: @Infamous911: Please share the code how you dispatch the action

Comment: Please share your `state` structure in the `state = initalState`

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN added

Comment: @Isaac added above

Comment: Also add setData, how u calling from mapdispatchtoprop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating from react-native v0.56 to v0.57. Apparently there was a problem with react-redux v6 working properly in the react-native v0.56 environment.

Comment: I have this issue and I'm using react-native v0.59 and react-redux v7.1.0. I have a prop 'loading' from my store that should trigger a loading indicator in a scrollview when fetching data. none of it is working atm

Comment: react-redux 7 use react hooks and they are not available in react-native for moment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a recent version of React, `componentWillReceiveProps` is actually [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops):

> Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies

You can't really rely on that lifecycle hook in a number of situations. You may want to look at a slightly different approach with `componentDidUpdate` instead.

Comment: Personally think that this suits more of a comment than an answer as it doesnt solve OP problem

Answer (score 0):

I think more important is to get the value after changing in state of redux rather than in which lifecycle you are getting the value . so for getting the value you can use subscribe method of redux in componentDidMount

```
store.subscribe( ()=> {
  var updatedStoreState = store.getState();
})
```

Comment: probably should not be doing this directly in the component

Comment: no as far as I know you can set  subscription or listener in componentDidMount

Comment: Of course you can do it, but directly accessing the store in a component is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I believe that getDerivedStateForProps would solve your problem.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.data !== prevState.data) {
    //Do something
  } else {
    //Do something else
  }
}
```

You would check the state from the redux against the state from your component and then act accordingly.

Also, some info from the documentation that you might consider before using this method:

**1.** getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates.

**2.** This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time.

**3.** If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

You can read more at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Doesn't work, `getDerivedStateFromProps` isn't called either

Comment: @Infamous911 what do you mean by 'isn't called'? The method is called before the render() automatically

Comment: @kivul if the components not re-rendering then it doesn't serve any purpose

Comment: @kivul yeah the component isn't re rendering when it should

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for this ...? its almost July :(